# On convergence in probability given a bound on the random variable.

Tags: probability, limits, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

I am dealing with the end of a proof:

[image]

Could somebody please clarify for me the extra steps needed to show that $P(||\bar{W}_n - \mu||_{\infty} > 3\varepsilon) \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$? (the arrow pointer in the attached image is covering the subscript $n$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming as mentioned image that the two maxima (that I will denote by $M_n$ and $M'_n$) converge to $0$ in probability, we have, by the bound of the displayed equation,
$$\tag{*}  \left\{\lVert \overline{W_n} -\mu\rVert_\infty\gt 3\varepsilon \right\}\subset 
\left\{2\varepsilon +M_n+M'_n\gt 3\varepsilon\right\} =\left\{M_n+M'_n\gt \varepsilon\right\}.$$
Next, since $\{M_n\leqslant \varepsilon /2\}\cap \{M'_n\leqslant \varepsilon /2\}\subset \{M_n +M'_n\leqslant \varepsilon\}$, we have 
$$\mathbb P\left\{ M_n +M'_n\gt \varepsilon \right\}\leqslant 
\mathbb P\left\{ M_n \gt \varepsilon /2 \right\}+\mathbb P\left\{ M'_n \gt \varepsilon /2 \right\},$$
hence in view of (*), 
$$\mathbb P\left\{\lVert \overline{W_n} -\mu\rVert_\infty\gt 3\varepsilon \right\}\leqslant 
\mathbb P\left\{ M_n \gt \varepsilon /2 \right\}+\mathbb P\left\{ M'_n \gt \varepsilon /2 \right\}.$$
Now it is not hard to conclude from the definition of the convergence in probability.